# Separate 2 Bytes Hexadecimal in 1 variable into 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I have

```
2bytes=0x1AFF
```

and I want to split the variable "2Bytes" to save 0x1A in one independent variable, and 0xFF in another independent variable. Saving in one variable the first byte and in the another the second:

```
Byte1=0x1A
Byte=0xFF
```

How can I do that ? Thanks

Comment: Use bit shifting and masking operators. Read https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators

Comment: If I do that, I will get the separation, but I will still have 2 bytes of 16bits, I mean Byte1=0x001A and Byte would be 0x00FF and what i want is these two to be of 8 bit.

Comment: Python doesn't have different sizes of numbers. An 8-bit number is just a number whose high bits are all 0.

Comment: So there's no difference between `0x00FF` and `0xFF`.

Comment: Perfect, Thanks a bunch @Barmar!!! I didn't know that.

Answer (score 3):

I would use the bitwise and `&` and bit shifting `>>` operators:

```
value = 0x1AFF
values = []
while value != 0:
    values.append(value & 0xFF)
    value = value >> 8

print(values)
# [255, 26]
# ==
# [0xFF, 0x1A]
```

This should produce the bytes (in reverse order) of `value` as a list in the variable `values`.

Comment: Yes! That's what I used. Thanks for your answer!